# Creating a Youtube bot

Tags: c#, php, javascript, c++, bots

I have a problem that I need to solve.

I create Youtube videos and every time I'm on the upload page I have to :

- remove the ".mp4" extension from every title
- change my video category
- put the same description in all of the videos
- put the same keywords in all of the videos

So, I firstly wanted to create this bot in C#, but I would have to learn C# (I already know C++, but again, I would have to learn all the libraries in C#).

I was wondering if this bot could be created in Javascript (because I already know Javascript) or in any other language that I know (PHP, C++)?

Maybe I can create a Mozilla Firefox extension that does it for me in Javascript? As I said, could someone just tell me in what programming (or scripting) language am I supposed to write this bot?

So, as I said, I would manually log in, bot would just need to access my already opened page in Mozilla Firefox and change that four things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @Matt he wants to know, which tool(s) to use ... not really the kind of question where the "What have you tried?" question makes sense ...

Comment: @Hinek in that case, this question is likely to open up a debate in the form of "this is better because...". -1 either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go with javascript on this one. Take a look at [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) - Scripting add-on for FireFox, that allows you to add custom javascript code to pages.

I would create a script that does all your needed changes when you call this script.

Or if all these things are on the same page you can use simple [bookmarklet](http://www.bookmarklets.com/about/) that calls javascript and changes these things for you.
I'm not too familiar with video uploading on youtube, so can't help you there, but you mentioned that you are familiar with javascript, so finding input fields with values and changing them shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: Just to say this, description would be always the same, but keywords would change. Do I still want to use GreaseMonkey or do I use something else?

Comment: Then you can add confirm box to bookmarklet / greasemonkey script that asks for keywords to input. I assume you will still have to input these keywords somewhere, so you can't really automate this part simply..

Comment: Ok, I'm going to use GreaseMonkey and create a custom script. Thank you. Just one more question - Where do I develop these custom scripts? Can I develop them in Notepad++ or does GreaseMonkey have integrated editor?

Comment: GreaseMonkey does not have an integrated editor as far as I know. You can develop your script in editor of your choice and then just drag and drop in firefox :)